# Modify Drupal's search to show custom fields

Tags: 7, search

I have some fields (say, pictures or whatever) in my custom `content-type` and I want them to appear in search results. How do I do that?

I know how to edit template files such as `search-result.tpl.php` provided by the search module. In this page, there is a single variable called `$snippet` which contains search result but as a rendered HTML output. How do I modify it/show my custom fields in search results?

I would like to have full control to contents of the files, rather than just rendered HTML for them. My Search display page requires customization a lot, so without getting each field individually, I won't be able to produce desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) module. There you can change the appereance of a content type in different view modes. One of these view modes is for example the search result.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.api.php/function/hook_update_index/7) shows the info you need to customize the indexing of your fields.

As for the output, [this one](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.api.php/function/hook_search_preprocess/7) should lead you on the correct path.

Comment: How does `hook_search_preprocess` take me to correct path?!

Comment: I mean : the path to follow to learn how to customize your result page.